# How can I find elements in a list that have same value in Python?

Tags: python

My question is how can I find strings in a list that have the same number of characters if my list is...

```
myList = ["Hello", "How","are", "you"]
```

and I want it to return the strings that are of value 3

example from above list...

```
["How","are","you"]
```

This is what I've tried...

```
def listNum(myList, x):
    for i in range(len(myList)):
        if i == x:
            return(i)



myList = ["Hello", "How","are", "you"]
x = 3
listNum(myList, x)
```

Comment: `[word for word in myList if len(word) == x]`

Comment: what means `same value`?

Comment: String literals evaluate to themselves, so `"How"` has the value `"How"`, `"are"` has the value `"are"`, and `"you"` has the value `"you"`. They very much do *not* have the same value, nor do they have the value `3` (or any integer for that matter).

Comment: I edited it, please let me know it that helps better understand what I'm asking.

Comment: filter(lambda x: len(x) == 3, myList)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is off because you are comparing the list ***index*** to the value you are trying to match with `i == x`. You want to use `myList[i] == x`. But it seems you actually want to check the length, so `len(myList[i]) == x`.

However, I prefer iterating over the actual elements in a loop (or list comprehension as noted in comments by Joran Beasley). You also mentioned that you wanted to check if for *string* of certain length, so you can also add a check for the object type:

```
def listNum(myList, x):
    return [item for item in myList if type(item) is str and len(item) == x]
```

Comment: The solution you mentioned has already been in comment section of question from Joran Beasley

Comment: I realize, but I wanted to provide a more complete answer with more than just the code.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `setdefault()` method. This solution should give you a dictionary of all the word lengths mapped to their respective words

**CODE**

```
myList = ["Hello", "How","are", "you"]

dict1 = {}
for ele in myList:
    key = len(ele)
    dict1.setdefault(key, [])
    dict1[key].append(ele)
```

**OUTPUT**

I guess this is the output you are trying to achieve.

```
>>> print(dict1)
{5: ['Hello'], 3: ['How', 'are', 'you']}
```

You can use this to query the dictionary and get the words corresponding to their word lengths. For e.g. `dict1[5]` would return `'hello'`

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use it for further enhancement i suggest you make dict in one loop then you can easily retrieve that for any number of characters. if you search for x=3 or 4 each time you have to go through your list. rather then that make dict with one loop.

```
myList = ["Hello", "How","are", "you"]

data = {}
for i in myList:
    if len(i) in data:
        data[len(i)].append(i)
    else:
        data[len(i)] = [i]

# print(data)

x = 3
print(data[x])
```

**output:**

```
['How', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use Python `filter` function here.

```
# list
myList = ["Hello", "How","are", "you"]

# function that examines each element in an array and returns it if True
def filterData(item):
    if(len(item) == 3):
        return True
    else:
        return False

# filter function that takes 'function-to-run' and an array
filtered = filter(filterData, myList)

# result
print('The filtered strings are:')
for item in filtered:
    print(item)
```

Hope it helped. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `groupby()` with a sorted list:

```
from itertools import groupby

myList = ["Hello", "How", "are", "you"]

f = lambda x: len(x)
l = sorted(myList, key=f)
r = {k: list(g) for k, g in groupby(l, key=f)}
# {3: ['How', 'are', 'you'], 5: ['Hello']}
r[3]
# ['How', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

**Code**

```
def func_same_length(array,index):
    res = [array[i] for i in range(0,len(array)) if len(array[index]) == len(array[i]) and i!=index]
    return res



myList = ["Hello", "How", "are", "you"]
resSet = set()
for index in range(0,len(myList)):
    res = func_same_length(myList,index)
    for i in res:
        resSet.add(i)

print(resSet)
```

**Output**

```
{'How', 'are', 'you'}
```